# How to have second section float below the first section?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following HTML markup, where I have successfully made the first section sticky.

What I want is the second section to be sticky as well but stay below the first one.

Suppose I scroll and the first section is sticky the second should be sticky and float below the first one.

How can I make the second section also float below the section-1.

```css
.section-1 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 1519.2px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 68px;
  transition: background 0.3s, border 0.3s, border-radius 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 06px 20px 0px 20px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.section-2 {
  transition: none 0s ease 0s;
  animation: 0s ease 0s 1 normal none running none;
  max-height: 68px;
  transition: background 0.3s, border 0.3s, border-radius 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding: 06px 20px 0px 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
}

.container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="section-1">Section 1</section>
  <section class=section-2>Section 2</section>
</div>
```

So when I try scrolling what is do currently the second section stays at the top while the first one scrolls. You can see this in live-action this website when you click the burger menu. [Sample Website](http://dani.wphigher.com/)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to a [mcve] that shows the issue

Comment: @mplungjan Yes sure thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using flexbox for this.

Add this to the container:

```
display: flex;
/* the line beneath reverses the order of the columns */
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

Here is a complete guide to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Check this example, it should be what you need. You can also use instead of the sticky - fixed

```
.section-1 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 6px 20px 0px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.section-2 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 6px 20px 0px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  height: 300vh;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ud470byo/3/